# Not able to get the result of a query in my database in a middleware with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the async result of a query for authenticate the users, but I am not getting anything in my console or in the variable, in fact I'm not pretty sure if I can return something from a middleware. This is my code:

The endpoint:

```
app.get("/login/", verifyUser, userController.login);
```

The middleware:

```
function verifyUser(req, res, next) {
  let user = userController.findUserOne;
  next();
}
```

And the findUser method in my controller:

```
exports.findUserOne = function (req, res) {
  const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const user = await db
        .collection("users")
        .where("user", "==", req.query.user)
        .where("password", "==", req.query.password);
      if (!user) {
        throw new Error();
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(401).send({ error: "Please authenticate." });
    }
  };
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your middleware, you are seemingly not calling the function, you are just assigning it to another variable: `let user = userController.findUserOne;`

Comment: Sorry how can I call the function? I have to send the parameters(req, res, next)? Besides that how I have to use the next() method? Sorry I am starting with NodeJs and JavaScript, so I am very confuse.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not querying any data:

```
      const user = await db
        .collection("users")
        .where("user", "==", req.query.user)
        .where("password", "==", req.query.password);
```

All you're doing here is building a [Query](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html) object, which hasn't accessed any data yet.  You will have to call [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#get) on it to actually execute the query.

`get()` returns a promise that resolves with a QuerySnapshot that you will have to dig into to see if a matching document was found.  Your code should look more like this instead:

```
      const query = db
        .collection("users")
        .where("user", "==", req.query.user)
        .where("password", "==", req.query.password);
      const querySnapshot = await query.get();
      if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
          // do something with the documents inside
      }
```

Comment: How can I call the database from the callback?